# MAMP Pro .xip.io, fixing urls with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mamp-pro

I've got all my websites set up with MAMP Pro. For instance, I got it set up, so when I go to example.com, the browser displays the website that's set up on my iMac.

Now, I wanna get MAMP Pro to work so I can view my website on my other computers/devices (which are all hooked up on the same network.) So far all I had to do is check the checkbox "via Xip.io (LAN only)", and now I can view my website on my other computers/devices within my LAN by simply going to example.com.10.0.1.13.xip.io.

Problem is, whenever I'm on this other computer/device, when I click on the links, I get 404 error. ie. whenever I go to example.com/news, I get the 404. But when I go to example.com.10.0.1.13.xip.io/news, THEN I get the right page.

So in order to solve my problem I need to rewrite the urls. So whenever someone clicks on a link ie. goes straight to example.com/news, he'll go to example.com.10.0.1.13.xip.io/news.

I don't want to change all the links in my MySQL file, but I believe I can do it simply with the htaccess file.

I've opened the htaccess file and added the last two lines, but it just doesn't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com.10.0.1.13.xip.io/$1 [R=permanent,L]

</IfModule>
```

Or perhaps I don't need to change the htaccess file, is there something that I could be missing in the MAMP Pro settings, or perhaps a MAMP extension that I need?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it working, now.

The website is built on WP, so I had to add these lines to the config file;

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://www.hugheslimousines.com.au.10.10.10.166.xip.io/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com.10.0.1.13.xip.io/');
```